# Split value of a column in Oracle

Tags: oracle

i have a column in wich the result appears like this:

- Column 1
- 999999999990
- 000000000000
- 999999999000
- 999999999900

The characters represents the past 12 months so I want to know if there is any built-in function in Oracle 10 so I can split the values in columns? I mean like

- Column1 Column2... Column 12
- 9    9     0
- 0    0     0

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure

```
SELECT substr( <<column name>>, 1, 1 ) column1,
       substr( <<column name>>, 2, 1 ) column2,
       substr( <<column name>>, 3, 1 ) column3,
       ...
       substr( <<column name>>, 12, 1 ) column12
  FROM <<table name>>
```

The `SUBSTR` function takes three arguments-- the string, the starting position, and the length.  So `SUBSTR( <<column name>>, 3, 1)` tells Oracle to go to the third character of the string and get a 1-character substring.  That will be the third character of the string.

Comment: The first number is the Starting Character while the Second Number declares the length of the String. FYI

Comment: @aRsen49 - I'm not sure that I understand what you're saying.  Do you know something about the data that I'm missing?

Comment: Oh no. Your answer is right. I was just explaining your answer a bit more, in case he wouldn t understand what the "1, 1" "2, 1" etc. stands for. I just recalled that when I learned programming for the first time, I thought the first number stands for the starting character and the 2. for the ending character. ;)